# File types in Ubuntu where are they located?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, lubuntu, configuration, filemanager

In file managers I can see file types which are specific for each file extension, but some descriptions are very long!

[image]
[image]

I have some that are even longer, but they elude me at  this time.

How do I make them shorter, or where are these descriptions hidden in the file-system.
Over the last 2-3 years they just keep getting longer, not more useful!
Its the same for all the file-managers in all the Ubuntu flavors I have tried, even other brands like Suse and Fedora!

Now they take up too much screen space, without adding anything more useful.

Comment: You're saying "Tar archive (gzip-compressed)" for example, is an excessively long description, and you want to know where the file browser gets this description so that you can change it?

Comment: Yes exactly, we know that tar.gz are compressed archives, and the g is short for gzip, archive or tar archive would be sufficient. Less in a couble of years we will get whole stories of all the different names!!

Comment: Can't you reduce the width of the `Type` column?

Comment: Yes and I removed the checkmark in the expand automatically checkbox, but where dos our filemanagers find those stories??